# Filter last month even in January

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The filter below works for most months. However, in January I also want to pull December of the last year.

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)-1 returns 0
```

and

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

How can I change this filter to make it more dynamic for every month of the year.

```
WHERE MONTH= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)-1 AND YEAR = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps? `ADD_MONTHS` will *subtract* 1 month from `sysdate` (the result is `DATE` datatype so you have to apply `to_char` to it and, possibly, to_number (depending on what the `month` column contains)). Year, on the other hand, depends on current month - if it is January, take previous year; otherwise, take current year.

```
where month = to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm')
  and year  = case when extract(month from sysdate) = 1 then extract(year from sysdate) - 1
                   else extract(year from sysdate)
              end
```

Comment: All parts of the desired date may be calculated in the same way: `extract(<part> from add_months(sysdate, -1))` or `to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), '<format>')` depending on the data type of a column (to avoid implicit conversions)

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
WHERE month = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MM'))
  AND year =  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtract a month before using `EXTRACT`:

```sql
WHERE MONTH = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1))
AND   YEAR  = EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1))
```